# Consumable IAP can't be purchased multiple times

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I sell multiple consumable IAP in an iOS application, but I can only purchase each consumable once.
When I try to purchase it a second time, this message pops up:

[image: IAP Error]

Is it related to the sandbox environment? The status returned from

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

is `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`. How should I handle it?

Comment: It looks like you have define your product as a non-consumable.

Comment: Nope. I've checked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't calling

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

appropriately.

Comment: Elaborate more what was missing.

Comment: @khunshan You have to call the mentioned function, after you have successfully purchased the good.

Comment: yea i do. the issue is coming when i press purchase and close the app. so the purchase is in progress and this method was not called ever. i believe the transaction was never rolled back and this message started appearing.

Comment: @khunshan do you know how to roll it back? Without having to create an new product?